# Closed form solution for a single layer linear perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

Let f be a one-layer neural network which is linear (ie. no activation function). Let it have $p$ inputs and $q$ outputs. These are fully connected by weights $W$. We have $n$ inputs $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $n$ outputs $y \in \mathbb{R}^{d'}$. We arrange these (column) vectors into matrices $Y$ and $X$, and the weights into a matrix, so that we can express the computation of the network on the whole dataset as $WX = Y$ (that is, if we could find the perfect $W$). Just to clarify, the network contains no hidden layer, just the input and output layers.

Training the network is a matter of choosing $W$ to minimize $e_W = \sum_{i=1}^n||y_i - Wx_i||^2$.

It seems to me that this problem should have a closed form solution that can be solved by a linear solver in some way. Unfortunately, my linear algebra is lacking. Is there a closed form solution? If not, where is the difficulty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a closed form solution.

In the most general terms, $WX = Y$ is a linear equation, so it can be solved as $W = X^{-1}Y$. If $X$ has no inverse, using the [pseudo-inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) $X^\dagger = X^T(XX^T)^{-1}$ will give the $W$ that minimizes $\sum_i||Wx_i - y_i||^2$.

For practical computation, it's best to compute the pseudo-inverse from a matrix decomposition, rather than multiplying the matrices explicity. The safest option is the [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). The wikipedia article details the procedure.

The principle behind this solution used only basic calculus. Calling the error $E$, we set $\frac{\partial E}{\partial w_{ij}} = 0$ and solve for $w_{ij}$. This is detailed in [1, pages 89–93) and [2], both available online.

Alternative phrases for this problem are **multivariate linear regression** and **affine registration**.

[1] [Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition](http://www.engineering.upm.ro/master-ie/sacpi/mat_did/info068/docum/Neural%20Networks%20for%20Pattern%20Recognition.pdf), Christopher M. Bishop.

[2] [Fitting affine and orthogonal transformations between two sets of points](http://hrcak.srce.hr/file/1425), Helmuth Späth, 2004

Comment: Is it possible to find a closed-form solution if there is an activation function? And will the closed form solution also provide the best approximation if the equation has no perfect solution? If w, x, and y are scalars ,for example, and the training data for (x,y) are (1,1) and (1,2), then an optimal solution (under a MSE loss function) would be w = 1.5.

Comment: It's definitely possible if the activation is invertible, like a sigmoid or a tanh. Then you can just pass the targets through the inverse activation. This doesn't work for something non-invertible like a ReLU, but you could probably figure out something specific for the ReLU. If there is no exact solution, then the pseudo-inverse will give you the least squares solution (i.e. the output closest to the target).

Comment: Tanks for the tip, @peter. I ended up implementing it. Trivial, once you remember the basic rules of linear algebra and a pseudo-inverse (which conveniently is included in tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/pinv) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71792056/closed-form-solution-to-single-layer-perceptron.